# Lower bounding the smallest eigenvalue of this PSD matrix (or tips for general PSD matrices)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm looking for some ways to lower bound the smallest eigenvalue of a positive semidefinite matrix. I'm specifically considering the following matrix, but general tips could be helpful too.

Below, the $q_r$ are positive integers and $1 > |\mu_1| > |\mu_2| > \dots > |\mu_m|.$ The matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix} \sum_{r=1}^m q_r \mu_r^4 & \sum_{r=1}^m q_r \mu_r^5 & \dots & \sum_{r=1}^m q_r \mu_r^{m+3} \\ \sum_{r=1}^m q_r \mu_r^5 & \sum_{r=1}^m q_r \mu_r^6 & \dots & \sum_{r=1}^m q_r \mu_r^{m+4} \\ \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\
\sum_{r=1}^m q_r \mu_r^{m+3} & \sum_{r=1}^m q_r \mu_r^{m+4} & \dots & \sum_{r=1}^m q_r \mu_r^{2m+2} \end{pmatrix}.$$

I imagine a bound should depend on $|\mu_m|$ (the smallest absolute value eigenvalue), as well as the gaps $|\mu_i - \mu_{i+1}|,$ since this will affect the singular-ness of the matrix.

If this is a standard problem, then some references would also be appreciated!

EDIT: If helpful, one could also assume that all of the $q_r = 1$, this would also be helpful to know the answer to.